# Stop Working of services in android from another activity

Tags: java, android

I am using services for updating the location. I make a call from my main activity and start the services as well... Now it enters to another activity but i cant able to stop the running services which i started in the previous activity.

Comment: Please post your code of what you tried. We can't help you if we don't post more informations

Comment: Actually service is start from the broadcast receiver and i want to stop it from main activity @nbe_42

Comment: Does your service is bound to an activity ? 
Which code do you use in your receiver and in your activity?